# JOIN only one row from second table and if no rows exist return null

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

In this query I need to show all records from the left table and only the records from the right table where the result is the highest date.

Current query:

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM users a 
INNER JOIN payments c
    ON a.id = c.user_ID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_ID, MAX(date) maxDate
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY user_ID
) b ON c.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
        c.date = b.maxDate
WHERE a.package = 1
```

This returns all records where the join is valid, but I need to show all users and if they didn't make a payment yet the fields from the payments table should be null.

I could use a union to show the other rows:

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM users a 
INNER JOIN payments c
    ON a.id = c.user_ID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_ID, MAX(date) maxDate
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY user_ID
) b ON c.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
        c.date = b.maxDate
WHERE a.package = 1
union
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM users a 
--here I would need to join with payments table to get the columns from the payments table, 
but where the user doesn't have a payment yet
WHERE a.package = 1
```

The option to use the union doesn't seem like a good solution, but that's what I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in other words, you want a list of users and the last payment for each.

You can use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `INNER JOIN` to get the last payment for each user.  The performance might be better and it will work the way you want regarding users with no payments.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   users a
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT * FROM payments c 
              WHERE c.user_id = a.user_id 
              ORDER BY c.date DESC 
              FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY ) b
WHERE a.package = 1;
```

Here is a generic version of the same concept that does not require your tables (for other readers).  It gives a list of database users and the most recently modified object for each user.  You can see it properly includes users that have no objects.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM  all_users a
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT * FROM all_objects b 
              WHERE b.owner = a.username 
              ORDER BY b.last_ddl_time desc 
              FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY ) b
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer from @Matthew McPeak but OUTER APPLY is 12c or higher and isn't very idiomatic Oracle, historically anyway. Here's a straight LEFT OUTER JOIN version:

```
SELECT *
FROM users a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    -- retrieve the list of payments for just those payments that are the maxdate per user
    SELECT payments.*
    FROM payments 
    JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(date) maxdate
            FROM payments
           GROUP BY user_id
          ) maxpayment_byuser
         ON maxpayment_byuser.maxdate = payments.date
            AND maxpayment_byuser.user_id = payments.user_id
) b ON a.ID = b.user_ID
```

If performance is an issue, you may find the following more performant but for simplicity you'll end up with an extra "maxdate" column.

```
SELECT *
FROM users a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    -- retrieve the list of payments for just those payments that are the maxdate per user
    SELECT *
    FROM (
           SELECT payments.*,
                  MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) maxdate
             FROM payments
         ) max_payments
    WHERE date = maxdate
) b ON a.ID = b.user_ID
```

Comment: I have 12c so his answer works. But I like your approach to +1

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach using `row_number()` is very useful for "highest date" or "most recent" or similar conditions:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM users a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      -- determine the row corresponding to "most recent"
      SELECT
            payments.*
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) is_recent
      FROM payments
) b ON a.ID = b.user_ID
      AND b.is_recent = 1
```

(reversing the `ORDER BY` within the over clause also enables "oldest")

Comment: Could you explain a little more about "oldest". +1

Comment: Look at the contents over the `over ( partition by ... order by ...)` WITHIN a "partition" the `order by` controls which row is given the value one. If you reverse the order yu reverse the row that gets one. Ie. You ca locste the "earliest" or reverse that and find the "oldest". I suggest you plsy with it a bit until it mskes sense.